# Write SAS Data-Labels to Excel file

Tags: sas

I try to write the labels of each variable to an Excelsheet in SAS. Im using the option `DBLABEL=YES`which allows you to print the labels as column headings in Excel. Unfortunately it seems that my Labels are too long. Does anybody has a solution? Here is the code I m using:

```
data test;
length a 3.
b 3.
c 3.;
input a b c;
label a = "this label is too long for writing it from sas to excel";
datalines; 
18 20 15
25 20 80
63 72 14
run;

libname xls oledb provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
preserve_tab_names=yes preserve_col_names=yes
datasource="f:my workspace\test_9.xls" provider_string="Excel 12.0";

data xls.test (dblabel=yes);
set test; 
run;

libname xls clear;
```

This is ther error I receive.

> ERROR: Error binding parameters: Invalid column name: this label is
>   too long for writing it from sas to excel

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the [SAS documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002261292.htm) there is a limit of 64 characters for labels written to Microsoft Access or Microsoft Excel files.

Comment: I can only write 32 characters. Any suggestions why!?

Comment: Try using EXCEL instead of XLS (if you have ACCESS to PC FILES).  I suspect XLS has a lower limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a problem with proc export instead.

```
proc export data=test outfile="C:\test.csv" label;
run;
```

Comment: If you have access to proc dbload, you can export to xls with the same label option as shown for proc export. I don't have though so I can't test it with my SAS install.